# Pyinstaller is not running properly

Tags: pyinstaller

I have a dash built on two .ipynb files. One is called "server" and the other "interface".

Everything is done correctly, the "interface.exe" file is created correctly, but when I run it, instead of opening my dash, it opens the "interface" code file. Does anyone know how to help me?

I've uninstalled pyinstaller, reinstalled it, tried everything, but every time I run the "interface.exe" file it only opens the code and I expect it to open the dashboard.